# PHP will not run from command line

Tags: macos, osx-server, php

When trying to run a PHP script from inside Terminal, the script is just echoed to stdout.  This happens if the script is executed directly (first line `#!/usr/bin/php`) called as an argument (`/usr/bin/php ./test.php`), or if the php command(s) is input interactively.

What could be the problem?

Computer is El Capitan Server, 10.11.6; and, no extra MAMP/Apache/PHP has been installed.  On a non-server El Capitan machine, things work as expected; so, I'm stumped...

Adding output of ls command:

```
sh-3.2# ls -lFa /usr/bin/php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  10577264 Jul  9 11:51 /usr/bin/php*
sh-3.2#
```

Adding more output:

```
sh-3.2# ls -lFa /var/root/test.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  17 Nov 21 16:48 /var/root/test.php*
sh-3.2# cat /var/root/test.php
<?
phpinfo();
?>
sh-3.2# /usr/bin/php /var/root/test.php
<?
phpinfo();
?>
sh-3.2# od -c /var/root/test.php
0000000    <   ?  \n   p   h   p   i   n   f   o   (   )   ;  \n   ?   >
0000020   \n                                                            
0000021
sh-3.2# od -x /var/root/test.php
0000000      3f3c    700a    7068    6e69    6f66    2928    0a3b    3e3f
0000020      000a                                                        
0000021
sh-3.2#
```

Comment: What is output from the command `ls -l /usr/bin/php`?

Comment: @GrahamMiln - Updated the question.

Comment: Thank you. Could the script contain non-ASCII characters or be UTF8+BOM formatted? If so, try [stripping these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337936/remove-non-ascii-characters-from-csv#3337960) as that could confuse the shell. Unlikely but worth a try. Also does, `/usr/bin/php <absolute path to test.php>` work?

Comment: Added more info, @GrahamMiln .   I also considered the UTF8 problem, because the original script I was running did have some Japanese comments.  But, as you can see, that's not an issue with the test script.  Running as root, to rule out permissions issues as well...

Comment: Use "<?php\nphpinfo();" instead of your test.php content. "\n" means new line (which I can't express in the comment here).

Comment: The "<?php" long tag did the trick!  Add that as an answer @klanomath , and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the long tag like

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

in test.php instead of your somehow malformed test.php and it should work.